# How can I proof this mathematical induction is correct?

Tags: calculus

How can i proof this mathematical induction is correct?

$$S(N)=\sum_i^N i=\frac{1}{2}N(N+1)$$,

this is they way that i don't know how to proof this mathematical induction is correct.
$a+(a+d)+(a+2d)+...+(a+(N-1)d)=na+?$
i don't know how to proof: $d+2d+...+(N-1)d=\frac{1}{2}N(N-1)d$

Comment: $\sum_{i=1}^Ni=N(N+1)/2$. The base case is trivial. Now suppose we have already proven for $N$. So 

$$\sum_{i=1}^{N+1}i=(N+1)+\sum_{i=1}^{N}i=(N+1)+N(N+1)/2=(N+1)(N+2)/2$$

Answer (score 1):

First, for N=1 we have $1=\frac{1(1+1)}{2}=1$.

Suppose that $1+2+...+N=\frac{1}{2}N(N+1)$ hold. Than we need to prove that $1+2+...+N+(N+1)=\frac{1}{2}(N+1)(N+2)$ hold as well:
$1+2+...+N+(N+1)=(1+2+...+N)+(N+1)=\frac{1}{2}N(N+1)+(N+1)=\frac{N(N+1)+2(N+1)}{2}=\frac{(N+1)(N+2)}{2}$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint : 
$$\begin{align}\sum_{i = 1}^{N}{i} &= N + \sum_{i = 1}^{N - 1}{i}\\
&= N + \frac{(N-1)((N - 1) + 1)}{2}\\
&= N + \frac{N(N - 1)}{2}\\
&= \frac{2N + N^2 - N}{2}\\
&= \frac{N^2 + N}{2}\\
&= \frac{N(N + 1)}{2}\end{align}$$

This means that if, for some $N$ the above holds true, then the case for $N + 1$ is true as well. Now just prove the base case, which is trivial : $1 = \frac{(1)(1 + 1)}{2}$.

From this, conclude that since the above holds true for $N = 1$, then it must hold true for $N = 2, 3, 4, \dots$ i.e. for all positive integers $N$.

Comment: and $1=\frac{1}{2}1\cdot 2$